# How to change the name of a Google Fit Session?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

While creating a new `Session` I can assign a name to it:

```
Session session = new Session.Builder()
    .setName(sessionName)
```

How can I change this name for an existing `Session` using the Google Fit API?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**`Users.sessions`**](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions), then use the [update](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/update) method which updates or inserts a given session.

HTTP request

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/userId/sessions/sessionId
```

See this tutorial - [Google Fit for Android: Sessions API](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-sessions-api--cms-25857) that demonstrates how to work with the Sessions API.

Hope this helps.